# HTML Elements display:initial or display:none changing upon checkbox state

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have created a little set-up with

and  elements, which I want to either be shown or hidden depending on the state of their designated checkbox. When the checkbox is checked, display:intial should be set, when the checkbox is unchecked, display:none should be set. However, I've been trying to find out how to do this with JS, but I haven't gotten anywhere. An example of the code I have:

```
<p id="nr_1" style="display: initial">Number 1 Example text here </p>
<input type="checkbox" id="nr_1" checked> Number 1</input>
<p style="display: initial" id="nr_1">
    <img src="src_nr_1.png">
</p>
```

The JS I've managed to scramble together from what I could find look like this:

```
function handleClick($id) {
    if (document.getElementById($id).display == checked) {
        var element = document.getElementById($id);
        element.style = "display:initial";
    }
    else {
        var element = document.getElementById($id);
        element.style = "display:initial";
    }
}
```

However, I haven't even been able to succesfully have the checkbox do ANYTHING. I've tried it with If/Else simply popping up an alert with texts to see if I had been able to have anything happen upon checking and unchecking the checkbox. It's probably very obvious from the constructions I've been building, but I've never used JS before. I imagine it has to do something with onClick() or onCheck(), but neither have seemed to respond to anything at all.

So what I'm trying to do here is have the JS react upon checking/unchecking a checkbox. I'd like to keep it as general as possible, because there's going to be somwhere between 10-25 checkboxes, and having to hardcode it for every different HTML element wouldn't be the most ideal situation. The checkbox, Text element and Image all have the same ID to match them with. So if Checkbox 1 gets checked, Text element 1 and Image 1 will appear. If it get's unchecked, they both disappear. Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You've got two elements with the same `id`: this is invalid, and will break any JavaScript using an `id`-selector.

Comment: In fact there are `three element with same id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes...
1) You cannot use id twice in a single page. JS will get confused :)
2) I doubt on getElementById($id).display == checked, because checked and unchecked are values of attribute 'checked'

The following code will work:

```
<p class="nr_1" style="display:initial"> Number 1 Example text here </p>
<input type="checkbox" title="nr_1" name="abccheck" checked onChange="callMe(this)"> Number 1</input> 
<p style="display:initial" class="nr_1"> <img src="src_nr_1.png"> </p>
```

and JavaScript:

```
function callMe(x)
{   
    var changeableTags=document.getElementsByClassName(x.getAttribute("title"));
    if(x.checked == true)
    {
        for(i=0; i<changeableTags.length; i++)
        {
        changeableTags[i].style.display="initial";
        }
    }
    else{
        for(i=0; i<changeableTags.length; i++)
        {
        changeableTags[i].style.display="none";
        }
    }
}
```

Here:

1. We called a function 'callMe' on state change of checkbox and pass the object (checkbox) into it by 'this'.
2. Now we took 'that' object in a variable 'x' in javascript and compare its title with class attribute on p elements (Because we need to hide and show more than one, so cannot use id)
3. Now by that comparison we took all the tags with class name (here 'nr_1') of title of checkbox... in our case its 'nr_1', in a single variable means array 'changeableTags'
4. Now if 'x' object's status is checked, we need to change its style to display:initial else display:none.
5. So we took a for loop till the length of our array named 'changeableTags'
6. And run it and change its each object's style as desired.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for the step by step explanation as well. This was exactly what I had in mind when I started off.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same id for different elements isn't something you can do. Instead, use a class, or a data-* attribute to link them together.

The (more) readable code that does what you want (the code assumes that all the elements that should be shown/hidden based on the checkbox checked state have among their classes a class with the same name as the id of the checkbox they depend on. *Note*: **do not** give the checkbox itself a class with the same name as its id, or it will disappear, too, with no chance of reappearing unless you script it somewhere):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .display-initial { display: initial; }
        .display-none { display: none; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <p class="nr_1"> Number 1 Example text here </p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nr_1"/><label for="nr_1">Number 1</label>
        <p class="nr_1"><img src="src_nr_1.png"></p>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p class="nr_2"> Number 2 Example text here </p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nr_2" checked/><label for="nr_2">Number 2</label>
        <p class="nr_2"><img src="src_nr_2.png"></p>
    </p>
    <p>
        <p class="nr_3"> Number 3 Example text here </p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nr_3" /><label for="nr_3">Number 3</label>
        <p class="nr_3"><img src="src_nr_3.png"></p>
    </p>
    <script>
        var checkboxes = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), function(element) { return element.type == "checkbox"; });
        checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
            function refreshDependentElements() {
                [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName(checkbox.id), function(dependentElement) {
                    if (checkbox.checked) {
                        dependentElement.classList.add('display-initial');
                        dependentElement.classList.remove('display-none');
                    } else {
                        dependentElement.classList.add('display-none');
                        dependentElement.classList.remove('display-initial');
                    }
                })
            }
            checkbox.onclick = refreshDependentElements;
            refreshDependentElements();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem with the code is that in this state, it depends on [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which are not supported in every browser (most notably, `IE9` and below). You could include the polyfills (given in the linked MDN pages), or here's a version that doesn't depend on them (just the code between the `<script>` and the `</script>` tags from above):

```
        function addClassToElement(element, className) {
            var currentClasses = element.className.split(' ');
            for (var iClass = 0; iClass < currentClasses.length; iClass++) {
                if (currentClasses[iClass] === className) return;
            }
            currentClasses.push(className);
            element.className = currentClasses.join(' ');
        }

        function removeClassFromElement(element, className) {
            var currentClasses = element.className.split(' ');
            var newClasses = [];
            for (var iClass = 0; iClass < currentClasses.length; iClass++) {
                if (currentClasses[iClass] !== className) newClasses.push(currentClasses[iClass]);
            }
            element.className = newClasses.join(' ');
        }

        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var iInput = 0; iInput < inputs.length; iInput++) {
            if (inputs[iInput].type !== 'checkbox') continue;
            (function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.onclick = function () {
                    var dependentElements = document.getElementsByClassName(checkbox.id);
                    for (var iElement = 0; iElement < dependentElements.length; iElement++) {
                        if (checkbox.checked) {
                            addClassToElement(dependentElements[iElement], 'display-initial');
                            removeClassFromElement(dependentElements[iElement], 'display-none');
                        } else {
                            addClassToElement(dependentElements[iElement], 'display-none');
                            removeClassFromElement(dependentElements[iElement], 'display-initial');
                        }
                    }
                }
                checkbox.onclick();
            })(inputs[iInput]);
        }
```

This code will work in all major browsers (`IE5.5+`, so no problems).

Answer (score 0):

If You use JQuery for this operation it can be done using following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chkboxId").click(function(){
        if($("#"+this.id).is(":checked")){
        $("#newelementid").show();
        }else
        $("newelementid").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/Lapekkv1/

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="nr_1" checked onchange="handleClick(this)"> Number 1</input>
<p style="display: initial" id="imageId">
    <img src="src_nr_1.png">
</p>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
       function handleClick(cb) {

        if( cb.checked){
        console.log(cb.checked);
        document.getElementById("imageId").style.display = "initial";

        }else{
        console.log( cb.checked);
        document.getElementById("imageId").style.display = "none";


        }
      }
</script>
```